# java.lang.NumberFormatException in Scala for mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I just trying to develop a simple example of a K-Means algorithm, but I have a lot of problems loading and cleaning the data.

This my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val crimeRDD = sc.textFile("/home/borja/spark/pruebas/AlgoritmoClusterizacion/filter_data1.csv")

val header = crimeRDD.first

val data = crimeRDD.filter (justData => justData != header)

//Spark doesn't allow more than 22 element
case class crimeReport (Record_ID: Int, Agency_Name: String, City: String, State: String, Year: Int, Month: String, Crime_Type: String, Crime_Solved: String, Victim_Sex: String, Victim_Age: Int, Victim_Race: String, Perpetrator_Sex: String, Perpetrator_Age: Int, Perpetrator_Race: String, Relationship: String, Victim_Count: Int)

val data_split = data.map(line => line.split(","))

val allData = data_split.map(p => crimeReport(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim.toString, p(2).trim.toString, p(3).trim.toString, p(4).trim.toInt, p(5).trim.toString, p(6).trim.toString, p(7).trim.toString, p(8).trim.toString, p(9).trim.toInt, p(10).trim.toString, p(11).trim.toString, p(12).trim.toInt, p(13).trim.toString,p(14).trim.toString, p(15).trim.toInt))

val allDF = allData.toDF()
allDF.printSchema
//allDF.show(100)

val rowsRDD = allDF.rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2), r.getString(3),r.getInt(4), r.getString(5), r.getString(6), r.getString(7),r.getString(8), r.getInt(9), r.getString(10), r.getString(11),r.getInt(12), r.getString(13),r.getString(14), r.getInt(15)))

rowsRDD.cache()

val features_vector = allDF.rdd.map(r => Vectors.dense(r.getInt(0)))

features_vector.cache()

val KMeansModel = KMeans.train(features_vector,2,40)
```

But I got this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 43.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 57, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Jersey"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
```

I do not understand it because I am cleaning the white and the spaces with the function *.trim*, do I?
The point is the exception is throw because there is some String value when I do the .toInt, right? So how can I filter them because there are 65k rows.

Here a little set of data:

```
Record ID,Agency Name,City,State,Year,Month,Crime Type,Crime Solved,Victim Sex,Victim Age,Victim Race,Perpetrator Sex,Perpetrator Age,Perpetrator Race,Relationship,Victim Count
1,Anchorage,Anchorage,Alaska,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Male,14,Native American/Alaska Native,Male,15,Native American/Alaska Native,Acquaintance,0
13504,Atlantic City,Atlantic,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Male,40,Black,Female,50,Black,Acquaintance,0
13505,Atlantic City,Atlantic,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Male,23,Black,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,0
13506,Atlantic City,Atlantic,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Male,52,White,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,0
13507,Atlantic City,Atlantic,Jersey,1980,March,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Male,35,Black,Male,23,Black,Unknown,0
13508,Atlantic City,Atlantic,Jersey,1980,March,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Male,25,Black,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,0
13647,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,October,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Female,50,White,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,2
13648,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,March,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Female,60,White,Male,36,White,Father,1
13649,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,June,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Female,52,Black,Male,26,Black,Unknown,1
13650,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,October,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Male,2,White,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,2
13651,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Female,68,Black,Male,0,Black,Unknown,0
13652,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Female,22,Black,Male,23,Black,Unknown,0
13653,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Female,16,White,Male,33,White,Acquaintance,0
13654,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,January,Murder or Manslaughter,Yes,Male,34,White,Male,18,White,Acquaintance,0
13655,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,February,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Male,29,Black,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,0
13656,Jersey City,Hudson,Jersey,1980,February,Murder or Manslaughter,No,Male,42,White,Unknown,0,Unknown,Unknown,0
```

Comment: look for the line containing `Jersey` (none of the example) and check how it stays after your cleaning steps. There's a bug somewhere probably (one of the values contains a string?)

Comment: Sorry for no include the lines with _"Jersey"_. Now the data appears after the transformations. The point is the exception is throw because there is some String value when I do the .toInt, right? So how can I filter them because there are 65k rows

Comment: `Try{data_split.map(p => crimeReport(...))}.recover{ case e: Throwable => logger.error(s"bad data: $p"); throw e}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the error message is thrown when an `object` cannot be casted to an `integer` value. 
Why don't you try `Option` or `Try` 
for example

```
Option(p(0).trim.toInt) getOrElse 0
```

Or

```
Try(p(0).trim.toInt) getOrElse 0
```

That should be enough to avoid such casting error

And you mentioned in your code that `case class` only supports 22 elements. This limit has been removed in newer versions of spark.
I hope the answer helps

Edited:
**Note :** `Option` catches `NullPointerException` only, so the casting exception shall not be solved. `Try` handles almost every kind of `Exception`, so `Try` should be the option for casting exceptions.

Comment: This is very bad approach because it hides problem.

Comment: This is the best approach I know of. If we want the problem to be evident (not hidden) then we can add `match` `case` and throw the necessary exception.

Comment: **Thanks all** for your help! Finally it worked with **_Try_**. With **_Option_** I still got the same error, but I don't Know why, could someone tells me the reason?. For the moment it's ok if the problem is hidden.

Comment: @Borja, yes certainly. I forgot that with `Option`, `NullPointerException` is only handled but with `Try` all of the `exceptions` are handled. Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Try` to handle the exception. You can use the old Java style `try/catch` or the functional way of `Try` in in scala. Below is the functional way of handling exception in scala.

```
Try(p(0).trim.toInt) match {
    case Success(result) => result  
    case Failure (ex) => {
      ex.printStackTrace()
      //return a default value as you want i have returned 0
      0
    }
  }
```

Try returns Success if the statement is passed and returns Failure if the statement fails or exception occurs. 
I hope this is more easier and understandable as well as functional.